# Building bed out of 8020 aluminium extrusion

Tags: aluminum

I want to build a [rock and roll bed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ5bowfjV7o) out of 8020 aluminium extrusion, in order to avoid the bother of welding steel pipe. However, I don't have much of a 'feel' for how strong this stuff is. Will 20x20mm T-Slot extrusion be strong enough to support the weight of two people (in a simple frame like the one in the link) or would I need to go for a thicker strength?

Many thanks!

Comment: Depends on the weight of the two people - among other varaibles...

Comment: About average - combined weight of max 120kg.

Comment: 120kg is an underestimate of "average weight of two adults". You want a reasonable safety factor as well. If I was designing this I would think 250kg was a minimum design load - and probably another 50% on top of that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight

Comment: Use cold extruded, warm extruded pipes are weaker than cold ones, if you can't find, then increase the safety factor. Look at IKEA catalogues, those piece of garbages are even weaker than a wooden splinter, but they still work !